# Meaning "I've got to know"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'd like know what is the correct meaning of this sentence: *I've got to know*

I don't know that sentence means like "I just understood", "I had to understand", or other...

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the word `imperitivity` isn't really a word in English, but it gets the point across, at least for me explaining the answer to your question.

As lurker pointed out, the closest relative would be `must`.  Though, that is a bit informal, and if not informal, it's much more demanding.

> I have got to have that guitar

vs

> I must have that guitar.

The first sentence suggests desire, while the second sentence suggests a need, a necessity.  Although, the first sentence can suggest the same thing, the second sentence is to the point.

> In order to play that particular piece of music I must have that guitar.

vs

> In order to play that [...] music I've got to have that guitar.

I believe the auxillary `got` is used more in America, and it is very relaxed, somewhat informal.

Here's a better example

> I have got to pee / I "gotta" pee

vs

> I must pee

To say that you *must* do something sounds a bit entitling.  It sounds very elitist.  It's almost as bad as telling someone,

> I shall pee

When in doubt, and you're in the US, just use *got to* / *gotta*

Answer (score 2):

> GOT (auxiliary verb)
>
> 2. (informal) must; have got (followed by an infinitive).

The two common synonyms are *must* and *need*. You can show off by using the archaic *must needs*.

This is street-level, conversational English at it's best. Anytime you see something you like in a shop window, or an attractive person walks by: *I've got to have it.*

You can dig even deeper into the world of slang with: That is *so mine*.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to ask possibly two different things

A) **You don't know something and want to know it**

> I've **got** to know
>   I **need** to know
>   I **must** know

Is telling someone you are **missing some sort of understanding** and want to learn about the pieces you are missing.  **Got** gives your sentence a **very strong desire**.

B) **You did not know something and now know it**

> I've **gotten** to know
>   I've **learned** about
>   I've **become familiar** with

These mean to **know about** something and **understand** what it is or how it works

Your example sentence

> I just understood

could mean two different things depending on context

> 1) **immediacy**
>
> > I **just** understood after you explained it to me
> >     I **just now** understood after you explained it to me *(this very moment)*
>
> 2) **limitation**
>
> > I **just** understood the beginning of the instructions and nothing else
> >     I **only** undertook the beginning of the instructions and nothing else

Comment: Are you a native speaker? And is it really true that the sentence can be interpreted in two ways as you wrote in your answer ? Is there any other sources to support your opinion?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois  I am a native speaker and the two interpretations of "I **just** understood" (without firther context) might be "I **just** *(now)* understood" or "I **just** *(barely)* understood" which could also be "I *(only)* **just** understood".

Comment: I mean I've never come across **I've got to know** meant for **B**. IMO, **have got to** is used only to express kinds of **obligation**.